# Multiple (unwanted) executions when passing parameter to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, controller, action

I'm using Codeigniter,

I have a controller called 'Property' with an action called 'details'

the function defining the 'details' action takes 2 parameters:

so we have a url like this : ***example.com/property/details/23/Appartment-for-rent***

the first parameter is the ID of the record on db, the 2nd parameter is just for SEO purposes

the details action eventually increments the views of that record on the DB

**Problem :** 
when i use *http://example.com/property/details/23*
everything works fine
when i use the SEO link *http://example.com/property/details/23/Appartment-for-rent* **the script executes several times** which causes the views count to be inaccurate.
Here is the controller/action function:

```
public function details($propertyId){
        $this->load->model('model_property');
        $pageData['property'] = $this->model_property->getById($propertyId);

        if($pageData['property']!=null){
            $this->model_property->incrementViewById($pageData['property']->id);
            $this->load->view('_common/header');
            $this->load->view('_common/navigation');
            $this->load->view('property/details',$pageData);
            $this->load->view('_common/footer');

        }else{
            redirect(base_url().'error');
        }
    }
```

Here is the function that increments the views on the model:

```
public function incrementViewById($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->set('views', 'views+1', FALSE);

        $this->db->update('property');
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? What version of CI are you using?

Comment: As above, without seeing some code, there is nothing anyone can do to help you

Comment: Edited with code as requested, thanks for the feedback
The CI version is the latest 2.2.0

Comment: Just a side tip I noticed for your code - instead of using base_url().'error' you can pass the 'error' string as a parameter inside base_url() like so: base_url('error'). Won't fix the problem you have but keeps your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code so I'm wondering if you have any hooks set up or are running something like LiveReload? Or possibly you have something funky in your property model's constructor that is causing its increment function to fire? Have you tried using debug messages in the increment function to see if it actually firing multiple times?

Comment: No hooks set up, nothing really, its all straight forward, i'm placing all my bets on the HTTP part of the equation, its gotta be in the url rewriting or somthing, i just cant figure it out.

Comment: As far as debugging, i've put a file_put_contents("#\r\n","log.txt",FILE_APPEND) in the end of the action, it writes the  symbol many times, just as if there's a header redirect that's triggering by its self.

Comment: Anything in your routes file? I doubt that would cause redirects but it's possibly linked to something.